# VSC: how to start a task only once onFolderOpen?

Tags: visual-studio-code, task, reload

is there a way to specify a task which should only be run once `onFolderOpen`?

```
{
              "label" : "Create terminals",
              "dependsOn" : [ "root", "bin" ],
              // Mark as the default build task so cmd/ctrl+shift+b will create them
              "group" : {"kind" : "build", "isDefault" : true},
              // Try start the task on folder open
              "runOptions" : {"runOn" : "folderOpen", "instanceLimit" : 1}
}
```

This task should only start once, but it will start a next task each time I reload vsc.

This leads to many terminal windows, the more often I reload.
Is there an option to not start this task when reloading?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is within terminal settings:

[image]